# My WiFi Adapter keeps stopping

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, freeze

## Environment

- `Windows 7 x64` with `Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260`.
- In Device Manager, the driver date and version are `5/3/2016` and `18.33.3.2` respectively.
- The adapter is built-in (laptop).
- My network is 5GHZ

## Symptoms

- Unexpectedly, my WiFi adapter will stop working with what looks like a freeze
- I lose internet access but also access to my LAN
- Once the "freeze" occurs, I cannot disable the adapter from Device Manager. There is an endless "disabling" process.
- While the "disabling" process is ongoing (or more likely stuck), I cannot shutdown the computer normally (must hold power button for 4 secs).
- While the "freeze" or "disabling" process is ongoing, I cannot put the computer to sleep
- The only way I've found to recover is to restart the machine
- Before the "freeze" all seems to be working properly, including disabling/enabling the adapter
- The "freeze" has never occurred within 15-20 minutes of booting up and connecting. But beyond that all bets are off. Could be 30 minutes, could be 4hrs. I don't think I've ever gone longer than 6hrs or so.
- This has only been happening within the last 3 weeks or so, but I don't know what set it off (no software installs in that span, not even Windows Updates around the time it started)
- Device Manager's status window shows *"This device is working properly"*
- The other devices on the network (both wired and wireless) function properly

## What I've tried

- Disabling my firewall (I don't run antivirus)
- Updating the adapter [driver from Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/intel-wi-fi-products/intel-wireless-7200-series/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-7260.html).
- Repairing the driver (using the same install package above)
- Uninstalling the driver (from Device Manager) then re-installing it. Incidentally, if I uninstall the driver, when I reboot the computer Windows has re-installed an old version.
- Unchecking *"Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"* in Power Management
- Switching to a 2GHZ band (from my typical 5GHZ)
- Booting into Safe Mode with Networking
- Resetting the TCP/IP stack (command `netsh winsock reset`)
- Releasing the IP setup (command `netsh ip reset`)
- Flushing the DNS resolver (command `ipconfig /flushdns`)

None of these have helped. Is there a simple way to find out whether I'm dealing with a hardware problem?

Because the "freeze" can take several hours to occur, troubleshooting is really slow. Please be patient in waiting for report of whether your suggestions worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been checking this from the Intel pages?
-> Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software and Drivers for Windows 7* 
Date: 19-Jun-2016 Version: 19.0.1 (Latest) OS: Windows 7, 32-bit*, Windows 7, 64-bit* .

Comment: @BeetleJuice Oh, yeah, sorry -> http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/intel-wi-fi-products/intel-wireless-7200-series/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-7260.html . But, wouldn't it install a v19.0.1 19-Jun-2016 driver instead of the v18.33.3.2 for a few months back ...

Comment: I wondered the same. The install seems to complete successfully but the driver version in Device Manager continues to show 18... If I run the installer again, it just shows options to Repair, Modify or Uninstall (there's no Install or Update as there was the fist time I ran it, or after I uninstalled drivers). Oh, and the installer itself shows `v19.0.1` in the UI

Comment: @BeetleJuice OK, now I found an explanation to this, when you go further on the download procedure there will come some instructions with 
-> Note: Intel® PROSet software version = 19.0.1 Driver version = 19.0.1.1 for Windows 7* for 3168, 18260, 8260, 17265 and 3165. 
Driver version = 18.33.3.2 for Windows 7* for 7265, 7260, and 3160. i.e. different drivers for different boards/chips ...

Comment: Good catch; I see that

Comment: @BeetleJuice OK, thanks, but, sorry, still no real solution found for the random freeze problem after some 15-20mins after boot/connect ... so, now my best guess is during times developed heath-sensitivity of some component on the Wi-Fi board itself, which either may not be too believable, and next guess some collision/overflow due to a driver problem ...